# Prove that $r!=5x+1$ for some $r$ in $\mathbb{N}$ iff $x \in \{0,1\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, factorial

The statement is true if $r$ is either $0$ or $1$.

At $x=0$ : $r! = 1$ so $r = 0$ or $1$.

At $x=1$: $r! = 6$ so $r = 3$.

For any other value of $x$, $r$ won't belong to $\Bbb N$.

Comment: There's no question here?

Comment: @GFauxPas Check older titles..

Comment: Well guys I am really sorry for the missleading format, I'll try to make it clear at this comment. If 7Pr - 7Cr = 175. Then we can simplify this to r! - 1 / r! (7-r)! = 5/144. Now if we isolate the top to be r! - 1 = 5x where x is a constant. r has to be 3 to match the first equation but here x could be 23/5 and then we get r! = 4! But this won't match. How to proof that r will be 3?

Comment: If someone could edit the title and the body it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: @Paolo Leonetti

Comment: @ScottWilliams I tried to clarify title and question, is it fine now? If this was just a part of another question, as it seems from your comment, please post it in another thread. If you have problem with editing, we can modify it

Answer (score 6):

If $r$ is an integer $\ge 5$ then $r!$ is a multiple of $10$.

Otherwise you can check it by hand.